# Cannot iterate through two csv files and compare

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I'm relatively new to python (2.7) and need help looping through 2 CSV files. The first (outer loop) file is the row I want to write if certain conditions are met with the second (inner loop) file.

```
import csv

f = open('../CI Working Copy.csv')
with open('../first.csv', 'wb') as n:
    theWriter = csv.writer(n)
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    g = open('../second.csv')
    csv_g = csv.reader(g)
    for row in csv_f:
        cbd = row[3]
        ced = row[4]
        rbd = row[5]
        red = row[6]
        ciCn = row[10]
        for iRow in csv_g:
            cn = iRow[0]
            startDate = iRow[1]
            endDate = iRow[2]
            iId = iRow[3]
            writeRow = 'false'
            if ciCn == cn:
                if (cbd == startDate and ced == endDate) or (rbd == startDate and red == endDate):
                    theWriter.writerow(row)
    g.close()
f.close()
```

It makes it into the second (inner loop) file, but never returns to the outer loop. I only need to write the row from the first file.

Comment: Can you put also a sample of your csv files?

Comment: It actually does make it into the second loop. It just doesn't go to the second iteration of the first loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row of the first csv file, you consume all the second file, so you need to go back on the beginning of the second file on each iteration.

The solution is:

```
for row in csv_f:
        g.seek(0) #go at the start of the second file
        for iRow in csv_g:
            do_smth(iRow,row)
g.close()
```